# ios7 iPad wrong view size in Landscape mode

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7, autolayout, landscape

I have iPad application which uses iOS7 SDK with auto-layout.
my main view have a sub view which is a UITabBarController which programmatically creates it's view controller's (storyboard.instaniateViewController..).

Inside the views - when i'm in portrait mode - everything is fine. but when i move to landscape mode - the view's width is changed correctly, but the view's height remains as in Portrait mode.
The result is that my screen is truncated in a height.

Any ideas why it happens? constrains seems fine.
I can change it by programmatically change the vie's frame, but it doesn't seem right.

Thanks

Comment: Double check all your constraints.  They're clearly incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, i see what the problem was - somewhere up the view's hierarchy was defined:

```
[viewController.view setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth]
```

and that meant that the height was not flexible of course. the fix is easy once i saw it:

```
[viewController.view setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight]
```